# Transliteration with U option and capitalized option characters

Tags: perl

I am looking at [this](https://metacpan.org/source/NEILB/Net-Dict-2.21/examples/portuguese.pl#L61) source code example from the [`Net::Dict`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Dict) distribution. At line 61 there is:

```
$translation =~ y/[\200-\377]/[\200-\377]/UC;
```

I wonder if this was ever valid Perl code, and what it was supposed to do? I cannot get this to compile with perl 5.30. For example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $str = 'abc';
$str =~ y/[\200-\377]/[\200-\377]/UC;
```

gives output:

```
Bareword found where operator expected at ./p.pl line 5, near "y/[\200-\377]/[\200-\377]/UC"
syntax error at ./p.pl line 5, near "y/[\200-\377]/[\200-\377]/UC"
Execution of ./p.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

According to [perldoc perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) there is no `U` option for the `tr//` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/U` and `/C` flag were valid in Perl 5.6.0, cf [Perl 5.6.0's perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.6.0/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) (I don't know when they were introduced though). They were removed in Perl 5.7.0, as you can see in [perl570delta](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.0/perl570delta.html):

> The tr///C and tr///U features have been removed and will not return; the interface was a mistake. Sorry about that. For similar functionality, see pack('U0', ...) and pack('C0', ...).

They were also removed from Perl 5.6.1; see [perl561delta](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.0/perl561delta.html).

Note that the `Net::Dict` module was written in 1998, and the latest Perl version back then was 5.005. I guess that whomever updated the code since then missed this example.

The behavior of /U and /C in Perl 5.6.0 was:

> U    Translate to/from UTF-8.
> C    Translate to/from 8-bit char (octet).
>
> [...]
>
> The first /U or /C modifier applies to the left side of the translation. The second one applies to the right side. If present, these modifiers override the current utf8 state.

Comment: And tr ranges must be inside [ ... ]  at the past?

Comment: @Dada Thanks, I will submit a pull request to `Net::Dict` based on this information.

Comment: @k-mx, No, a harmless bug